# Pyomo TypeError when using matplotlib contour

Tags: python, contour, pyomo

I'm trying to construct a Pyomo model using "contour" from matplotlib. The code below reproduces the error which I get (this is not the complete model, but just a short code section that reproduces the error). For my model I need to know the contour of some shape (here I use a circle just to demonstrate the problem). What am I doing wrong here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyomo.environ as pmo

mesh_size = 1001
x_m = np.linspace(0, 1000, mesh_size)
y_m = np.linspace(0, 1000, mesh_size)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_m, y_m)


def circ(a, b):
    return (X - a) ** 2 + (Y - b) ** 2 - 10000


def m_rule(model):
    F = circ(model.x[1], model.x[2])
    expr = plt.contour(X, Y, F, [0]).allsegs[0][0]
    plt.close()  # otherwise "contour" plots a plot
    return expr


model = pmo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pmo.Var([1, 2], initialize=500)
model.o = pmo.Objective(rule=m_rule)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `sum' to a float is
> disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as
> arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
> defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math
> functions.

Answer (score -1):

You are minimizing a figure which is not correct
you should first optimise a clear objective function and then visualize it post solve

Comment: Actually I'm not. I use contour to get the coordinates of a new isoline polygon. Not for plotting a figure.

Comment: Please clearly define your objective function based on your decision variables first

Comment: I updated the objective function: the area of the isoline polygon
_def m_rule(model):
    F = circ(model.x[1], model.x[2])
    p = plt.contour(X, Y, F, [0]).allsegs[0][0]
    polys = gp.GeoSeries([Polygon(p)])
    isoline_df = gp.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys})
    expr = isoline_df.area_
but an error appears after the contour command